# Excel - formula for If/Then conditions with negative numbers

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm working on a file that will measure test results and identify gaps for required knowledge competency vs current knowledge competency. I have 5-6 competencies to measure for each person. The lowest gap would be -4 while the highest is 4.

| Conditions (IF) | Rating (THEN) |
| --- | --- |
| All gaps have negative values | Does not meet requirements |
| Has 1-2 negative values but with 1-2 zero gaps | Meets some requirements |
| All gaps are zero | Meets all requirements |
| 1-2 gaps are positive, can have zero | Exceeds some requirements |
| All gaps are positive and have no zero | Exceeds all requirements |

For example,

| Subjects | Gaps | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Competency 1 | 2 | 2 pts higher than expected |
| Competency 2 | -1 | Less than expected |
| Competency 3 | -1 | Less than expected |
| Competency 4 | -1 | Less than expected |
| Competency 5 | 0 | expected |
| Competency 6 | 1 | 1 pt higher than expected |
| Total Rating | Meets some requirements |  |

I've tried dissecting step-by-step and incorporating Index/Match/Mode formulas as well but I can't seem to make it work. I really need some help with this! Thank you in advance!

[image: With formula on address bar]

[image: Values only; without formula]

Comment: Hi! @BigBen I edited the question above. Hope it provides clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the gaps are in `B2:B7`, I believe this follows your logic:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,">=0")=0,"Does not meet",
 IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,0)=COUNT(B2:B7),"Meets all",
 IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,">0")=COUNT(B2:B7),"Exceeds all",
 IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,"<0")>0,"Meets some",
 "Exceeds some"))))
 &" requirements"
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast!! Just want to clarify, what does this last statement mean?  IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,"<0")>0,"Meets some",
 "Exceeds some"))))&" requirements"

Comment: That checks if some gaps are negative. If not, then some gaps are positive. The formula has previously checked whether all gaps or negative or all gaps are positive or all are zero... so the last check is for *some* gaps.

Comment: Hi Bigben! Just a clarification, the formula seems not to be recognizing negative values as it always returns to "Does not meet". The negative values as written in the example above have formulas as well to recognize the "gaps". I'm not sure why this is not working when negative values have formulas while formula is working if negative values are written just as is.

Comment: Can you edit your question with a screenshot? Can you give an example of the negative formula?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `-1` and `1` in your formulas. `"-1"` and `"1"` are text, not numbers.

Comment: Well you should remove the quotes around `2` and `3` too... didn't see those. Seems like you could use a lookup table with `VLOOKUP`  instead of that massive nested `IF`.